# Unable to eb ssh. Return error message ERROR: An error occurred while running: ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ssh-keys

i keep on running unto this problem after setting up a key pair with eb ssh --setup numerous times. How can I connect to ssh? I am using windows git.

```
$ eb ssh name-env
The authenticity of host '54.210.133.152 (54.210.133.152)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:JxdKl8dJXMsfF1EkPRBnOH4hT7Zw6PtfRuRJ7xNu0ao.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Host key verification failed.
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running ssh -i C:\Users\dav\.ssh\aws-eb ec2-user@54.210.133.142
ERROR: An error occurred while running: ssh.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your public keys are already associated with your EC2 instance, you will also need to make sure your private key has the proper permissions (mode) of `600`.
Note: In a *nix environment you would run a `chmod 600 /path/to/.ssh/private-key-file` but I'm not sure how that translates to file permissions in a Windows environment.